# How to bind Daphne on a unix socket?

Tags: django, unix, nginx, django-channels, daphne

So far, I've used [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), with this configuration file systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/user/.envvars
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/user
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/user/user.sock config.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='config.settings.production'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) proxy requests for this unix socket.

Trying [Daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne), I realized that I can not specify `--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='config.settings.production'`

But I specify this variable in `asgi.py`, on it all is normal.

As soon as I ran the `gunicorn service`, the socket itself was instantly created on which requests from `nginx`.

When I try to do the same trick with Daphne, I get an error:

> Jun 26 11:48:32 p435061.kvmvps daphne[8447]: ValueError: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 8: '/var/www/user/user.sock'

But I can not figure out how to use the `unix.sock` when I try to run `Daphne` and create my `systemd` file

***UPDATE***

I changed the settings file, and it gives something strange, but it works:

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/gglobal/.envvars
User=gglobal
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/gglobal
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/daphne -b unix:/var/www/gglobal/gglobal.sock  config.asgi:channel_layer -v2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

systemctl status daphne returns:

```
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,722 DEBUG    get 'RDS_HOSTNAME' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,722 DEBUG    get 'RDS_PORT' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,722 DEBUG    get 'REDIS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,722 DEBUG    get 'REDIS_PORT' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,723 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_DSN' casted as 'None' with default 'https://56bb387ee6ef4e7b
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,723 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_CLIENT' casted as 'None' with default 'raven.contrib.django.
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,723 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL' casted as '<class 'int'>' with default '20'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,724 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL' casted as '<class 'int'>' with default '20'
Jun 26 17:53:46 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: 2017-06-26 17:53:46,724 DEBUG    get 'DJANGO_ADMIN_URL' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
Jun 26 17:53:48 p435061.kvmvps daphne[14183]: DEBUG 2017-06-26 17:53:48,186 base 14183 140286354425600 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteCo
```

But nginx swears at the lack of a *.sock file:

```
2017/06/26 17:47:51 [crit] 12682#12682: *59 connect() to unix:/var/www/project/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.152.1.201, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/project/project.sock:/", host: "mydomain.com"
```

I spent the whole day fighting this, but nothing happened.

Comment: Looks like you use wrong arguments for Daphne. Something like instead of `-u <path to socke>` something like `-b <path to sock>`?

Comment: @ZadaZorg Should be indicated together -b and -u ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was quite simple:

The problem was that I pointed out `-b unix:`, and the `unix:` prefix interfered with the work, and, of course, the flag should be set `-u`

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/gglobal/.envvars
User=gglobal
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/gglobal
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/daphne -u /var/www/gglobal/gglobal.sock  config.asgi:channel_layer -v2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```